Does TWebRequest support HTML Anchors?
I want to see the entire url passed, using TWebRequest:
http://localhost/client#anchor
How do I see the # part?  I'd settle for the entire URL (uri) used, and parse it myself, but I don't think you can see that with TWebRequest either.
I've looked at all the TWebRequest properties, I don't see one that will return the entire raw url.

An Anchor (more formally known as a Fragment in the URI spec, RFC 3986) is not really part of the URL itself, and is rarely ever transmitted to a server. It is typically only used in a local browser window when displaying the HTML to the user. But TWebRequest is not a web browser. It is unlikely that you will ever see an Anchor/Fragment appear in a URL received by TWebRequest.

Turns out, using Chrome or probably any modern browser, you cannot send a raw # in the URL.  Chrome ignores it, and any characters after it, and only sends the characters UP-TO, the #.
You can receive a # in a response from a server, which directs the browser to position to that "Anchor" in the document just received.

It never makes sense for a HTTP server, because there no websites are displayed that need initial scrolling. Of course it can be in a HTTP response - otherwise you would have never experienced to be linked to a certain place of a long website. Your own application should be smart enough to not just send anything as a URI in a request.
